# Why "i" is not equals to "i̇"?

Tags: javascript, character

In the javascript console of google chrome type the following code:

```
"i" == "i̇"
```

and realize that it returns false. But both of them has the same char code (105).

How and why this is possible?

After comments, I realize second i has 2 characters, but second character was made from the following code:

```
 "İ".toLowerCase() // outputs i̇
```

also

```
"İ".length // returns 1
```

How and why javascript .toLowerCase() can count up the char length?

Comment: The second "i" isn't really an "i".

Comment: Just copy/paste the following code I wrote and see.

Comment: There's an extra character after the "i" in the second string.

Comment: @fauverism well you're right in a way, but both comparison operands are actually strings in this case.

Comment: @fauverism has nothing to do with that in this case....

Comment: It's true indeed this yields false http://jsfiddle.net/6j8w71tf/1/

Comment: `console.log(escape("i"), "==", escape("i̇"))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
console.log("i".length, "i̇".length)
> 1 2
```

The second string has an extra character. The result is `false` as the two strings are not the same.

If we use `charCodeAt()` we can see that this extra character is Unciode symbol 775, known as a [*combining dot above*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm).

> ̇ combining dot above `01407` `775` `0x307` `&#775;`

Comment: Hi can you explain this http://jsfiddle.net/6j8w71tf/2/ why it results false yet there length is the same

Comment: @Andrex, your jsfiddle does not show the length of `'i̇'` (with the combining dot) but twice the length of normal `'i'`.

Answer (score 5):

The right-hand string has two characters: an `i` and a "combining tilde" following that. You can tell just by looking closely at the title of your question!

Comment: @andrex the second string in your fiddle also includes another Unicode character (character 775, "combining dot above").

Comment: really?  how come in the 'i'.length both equal to one I don't believe you there is no extra character I used escape

Comment: @andrex what Pointy said above. If you modify your JSFiddle demo to log the length of the output of `escape()` on both of those characters, the length of the first is `1` whereas the length of the second is `7`. Your own `console.log()` is logging the length of the same value and is unrelated to the values of the data you're returning in the `alert()`.

Comment: @andrex try copy-pasting the second string and then call `.charCodeAt(1)`

Comment: But how come it's like that I typed it 'i' both the same.?  I just typed in manually I didn't do any copy paste but why does it not equal?

Comment: @andrex as I said, the values you're calling `console.log()` on are identical. The values you're calling `escape()` on are different.

Comment: @andrex they simply are not the same; see [this modification of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0u7apkrs/)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that's what I'm wondering how come they became different I typed them manually each 'i'

Comment: @andrex In simple terms what you're asking is "`a` and `b` are different. Why are `a` and `a` the same?" Your `alert()` call compares two different strings, whereas your `console.log()` call logs the length of the same string twice.

Comment: how come these are two different strings ? `alert(escape('i') == escape('i̇'));` all I'm seeing is both the letter i inside single quote.  I did typed them 'i' both by hand.  So that is what I want to know, why did they become two different character, what went wrong where?

Comment: @andrex we're not sitting next to you so we don't know :) In the jsfiddle you posted, in the `alert()` call, the right-hand string was different from the left-hand string. Why? I don't know. Yes, the strings **look** the same, but if you cut-and-paste carefully you'll see that the right string is 2 characters long. The second character is Unicode 775, "combining dot above".