# How does ascii work on JS? ascii 775 and other in-visible chars

Tags: javascript, unicode

when you call the function below
TF("Nis");
there is a problem, that JS produces, how can i prevent that

```js
   var TF =  async (term ) => {  

const dateMonthFormat = {
    OCAK: '01',
    ŞUBAT: '02',
    MART: '03',
    NİSAN: '04',
    MAYIS: '05',
    HAZİRAN: '06',
    TEMMUZ: '07',
    AĞUSTOS: '08',
    EYLÜL: '09',
    EKİM: '10',
    KASIM: '11',
    ARALIK: '12'
  }
 console.log(Object.keys(dateMonthFormat));

  function termChecker(item) {
      console.log(`%c term :::${ term.toLowerCase()}`, "color:orange;");
      console.log(`%c item :::${ item.toLowerCase()}`, "color:orange;");
      console.log((item.toLowerCase()).startsWith(term.toLowerCase()))
    return item.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase());
  }
  console.log(term.toLocaleUpperCase());
  console.log(Object.keys(dateMonthFormat));

  console.log(Object.keys(dateMonthFormat).find(termChecker));


}
```

The function given below does not work,
unless you replace 'i' on ni̇san to another ascii 105 'i'
it makes next letter " " (ascii 775) and then 's'

why and how it can be possible to "i" to carry an invisible (ascii 775)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "ni̇san";
  var n = str.startsWith("nis");
  console.log(n);
  console.log(str[0], " is ", str.charCodeAt(0));
  console.log(str[1], " is ", str.charCodeAt(1));
  console.log(str[2], " is ", str.charCodeAt(2));
  console.log(str[3], " is ", str.charCodeAt(3));

  console.log("nis".charCodeAt(0));
  console.log("nis".charCodeAt(1));
  console.log("nis".charCodeAt(2));

}

myFunction();
```

are there any other interesting chars like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You talk about ascii but this is not ascii, look e.g. at the docs for [`charCodeA`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt): *"returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code"* - `i̇` does not exist in ascii. And in the unicode there are TONS of "interesting characters" like that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: please don't link to such a site implying that this is in **any way** related to ASCII: ASCII is *dead*, no one uses it and it's only mentioned because people *think* it's relevant, when it's only relevance left these days is almost exclusively historical.

Comment: @Nico Haase i want to achieve taking the value of the element starts with term("nis")

Comment: Your problem arises through a peculiarity of the turkish written language. There exist two individial `i` characters. One with a dot (`i`) and one without (`ı`). This difference should be shown in capital letters as well: April: nisan NİSAN; May:mayıs MAYIS. Notice the dot above the capital I.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [*Why “i” is not equals to “i̇”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995451/why-i-is-not-equals-to-i̇)

Comment: @RobG thank you , i will delete question then

Answer (score 2):

ASCII doesn't work like that. You're looking at Unicode features.

`U+0307 : COMBINING DOT ABOVE` is a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character):

> In digital typography, combining characters are characters that are intended to modify other characters. The most common combining characters in the Latin script are the combining diacritical marks (including combining accents).

It's a system that lets you describe the dot above a letter once and then apply it to different letters. This means you don't need a unique character code for every single letter + dot above combination. You just use two character codes next to each other in the binary representation of the string.

Comment: i understood that it happens because of İ , now it works thank you